# Text Box does not immediately pop up in JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

I have attached a screenshot of what should be achieved the first time, but is only happening by resizing the window. The code will compile and run. It should take the color value from any location on the screen, but I can't seem to make the R G B box to be in the correct location the first time. Could someone please take a look?

[image]

Please note again, this is what should happen upon first execution, but is only happening via resizing.

```
import static com.sun.javafx.fxml.expression.Expression.add;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class RGBunderCursor {

public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException{
new RGBunderCursor().TestPane();
}

private JPanel fields;
private JTextField red, green, blue;
private JLabel label;
private BufferedImage img;
PointerInfo info = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
Point point = info.getLocation();

public void TestPane() throws AWTException {

JFrame frame = new JFrame("Get the RGB");
Container content = frame.getContentPane();   
fields = new JPanel();
//JTextArea RGBV = new JTextArea("test");
//frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

fields.setVisible(true);
content.add(fields);

frame.setSize(600, 600);
// frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

frame.setVisible(true);

        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        fields.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        red = new JTextField(3);
        green = new JTextField(3);
        blue = new JTextField(3);
        fields.add(red);
        fields.add(green);
        fields.add(blue);
        add(fields, gbc);

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.delay(2000);

while(true) {
   point = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();       
   Color color = robot.getPixelColor((int)point.getX(), (int)point.getY());
   red.setText(Integer.toString(color.getRed()));
   green.setText(Integer.toString(color.getGreen()));
   blue.setText(Integer.toString(color.getBlue()));
   fields.setBackground(color);
}

 }
 }
```

Comment: You're adding components to the JFrame **after** calling `setVisible(true)`, and by doing this, the components are not always visualized initially. The solution is simple.

Comment: This worked for me, if you would like to post this as an answer, I can mark it as correct and it will boost your reputation. Thank You! :D

Comment: It has already been asked and answered [many many times -- see links](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+swing+setvisible+true+after+all+components+have+been+added), and so I've closed your question as a duplicate.

Comment: I am aware, I just didn't know if you wanted the reputation points for answering it correctly or not.

Comment: .................nope

Comment: Okay, well thanks for answering it anyways. I really appreciate it :)